# Blue makeup at the hostess party

Tags: goodfellas

In the scene where Karen attends a hostess party for the first time, one of the women applies some kind of makeup to another woman's face that looks like blue frosting. What was that blue stuff used and what was its purpose?

Comment: https://www.buzzfeed.com/augustafalletta/inexpensive-sheet-masks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially this is a **Facial Mask** treatment

> A facial is a family of skin care treatments for the face, including steam, exfoliation, extraction, creams, lotions, **facial masks**, peels, and massage. They are normally performed in beauty salons, but are also a common spa treatment. They are used for general skin health as well as for specific skin conditions. Types of facials include European facial, LED light therapy facials, and mini-facials.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facial)</sup>

[image]